localhost refused to connect ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Error
I'm working with angular. And trying to run site on chrome browser. At that time it is giving me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. But I'm able to connect with site from FireFox Browser. On chrome, I follow this chrome://net-internals URL (as per one solution I found) and processed localhost with Delete domain security policies 2-3 times(one time doesn't work). After that it starts working. Can anybody explain what is exactly happening, that site doesn't work on chrome and works on FireFox with localhost:4200 URL. And after deleting localhost domain in chrome, why is it working on Chrome?

did you try to run with --disable-host-check?

I just used ng serve -o and my default browser is chrome.

try ng serve --disable-host-check - Don't verify connected clients are part of allowed hosts. This option has no effect when using the 'application' or other esbuild-based builders.
